# You roll a die 8 times and tabulate the results, counting the total number of 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s, 5s, and 6s rolled.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

You roll a die 8 times and tabulate the results, counting the total number of 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s, 5s, and 6s rolled.
For example, the table

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2 |

indicates that three 2s, one 3, two 5s and two 6s were rolled.

The questions are the following:
(a) How many tables are possible?
(b) How many possible tables contain zero zeroes?
(c) Is the probability that the table contains zero zeroes given by your answer to part (b) divided by your answer to part (a)? Answer yes or no, and justify your answer.

No need to give me the full answer, just a nudge in the right direction please!

Comment: See [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: For part c), you have to ask yourself if all tables are equally probable.